# how can I access a function that is created in another file in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

How can I access `loadHighScore:(int)score` function?

When ever I try to access this function, it gives an error saying:

`unrecognized selector instance, at [Sc LoadHighscore].`

```
  Sc *gameOverScene = [Sc node];

 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameOverScene];
```

What could be wrong?

Please Help and Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be following problems,

1. You are calling that function using Class name(With out the object).
2. You are calling that function with out passing the argument "score".

Check whether you doing wrong in any of above.